# Wordpress "I think you have a wrond seperator"

Tags: woocommerce

I am uploading my wordpress website database from excel. How ever getting this error

> I think you have the wrong separator. Please go to the settings page and change your separator!

Comment: Are you using woocommerce plugin in wordpress?

Comment: @BhumiShah Yes i am using woocommerce plugin..

Comment: @BhumiShah can you please reply if you know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the excel version problem as MS excel have no support for ; & ,. So if your database contains any of this symbol ms - excel will not support it. When you open such databse from ms-excel & made changes then Go to Save as & keep CSV format instead of default excel format & save it. That will definitely work.. 
 For more information refer [this link](http://hotware.wordpress.com/2009/12/16/trouble-with-opening-csv-files-with-excel-the-comma-and-semicolon-issue-in-excel-due-to-regional-settings-for-europe/)